# Login with python form requests

Tags: python, forms, authentication, web, python-requests

Good morning I need your help, I would like to perform some web scraping to this website, but where to login first, I made a code, but I can not understand if it works and the login is done correctly.. also if once I am connected to my account via python the session remains open`?
Thank you!

```
 `import requests

payload = {
         'j_username': 'username',
         'j_password': 'password'
    }

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/j_security_check', data=payload)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print (p)

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/main/matter/desktop/main-menu#duties')
    print (r.text)
        # etc...
```

Comment: maybe check `p.url` to see where you are redirected after login. Or check in `p.text` if there is element which exists only when you logged in - ie. text `logout`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! when i did this i get the same link back.

Comment: if you get the same URL then it may need something else - ie. headers like `User-Agent` to simulate real web browser.

Comment: when I tested it in browser with wrong data then it doesn't gives the same  url but `https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/login?login-status=failed` and HTML has text `Login failed. Please check your user name and password.` and if you get the same url then maybe you are logged in. You should check in browser what happend when you use good data, and what happend when you use wrong data. You could also see if after login browser display exactly the same elements - maybe it has button `logout` which you can search in code to confirm that you logged in.